# Causative-passive contracted form

Tags: passive-voice, contractions, causation

I'm working through the book Nihongo So-matome N3 Choukai and on one page there is a side note about contracting the causative-passive form (e.g. 待たせられる＝待たされる). Underneath it says 「食べる、話す、する、来る、などは縮約形にはできない。」meaning verbs like these don't have these contracted forms. する and 来る are the usual exceptions, 食べる is an 一段 verb, but what about 話す? Is there something special about this verb or a group that it's in? Why can it not be contracted in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [日本語教師のページ--受身使役](http://www.nihongokyoshi.co.jp/manbow/manbow.php?id=1022&TAB=1)

> 2）縮約形から使役受け身形を作る。
>   縮約形は、すべて五段活用動詞と同じ活用である。だから、活用語尾の[-u] を［-aseru] に変換すれば、使役受け身形ができる。
>   ①　五段活用動詞の場合
>   読む→読ます→読まされる（この形のほうが、上記「読ませられる」より一般的。しかし、**縮約形が「〜さす」の形になるものは、この形は使わない**）
>   話す→話さす（縮約形）→×話さされる
>   ②　一段活用の場合
>   食べる→食べさす→×食べさされる（上記と同じ理由）
>   ③　変格活用動詞
>   カ行変格活用動詞　来さす→×来さされる（上記と同じ理由）
>   サ行変格活用動詞　さす→×さされる（上記と同じ理由）

You don't use the ～される passive form for the verbs that take ～**さ**す as the contracted causative form. So basically you don't use ～**ささ**れる. <sub>(Compare: ～**た**す as in 待たす, ～**ま**す as in 読ます etc. can take the ～される passive form, as in ～**たさ**れる in 待たされる, ～**まさ**れる in 読まされる.)</sub>

<sub>...Although we often say things like 「食べさされたわ～」「来さされてん～」 etc. in casual conversation in Kansai.</sub>

Comment: `Why can it not be contracted in this way?` -- 「ささ」が言いにくい？カッコ悪いんでしょうかね・・なんとなく関西っぽいし。。

Comment: 関西っぽいって、その考え方？「ささ」をいうことそのもの？

Comment: Now that you've said this, it seems really obvious. I understood that this was the case for 一段 verbs but for some reason I didn't make the connection for ~す verbs. Thanks!

Comment: @macraf 「さされ…」ていうのが、なんか関西弁っぽいかな～と。「～さす」「～さした」とかもちょっと関西っぽいし。（関東だと、普通は「させる」「させた」ですかね？）